# ATL on CUDA occurs compilation error

Tags: c++, cuda, mfc, atl, nvcc

I have some problems using ATL (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ax346b7.aspx) on NVdia Cuda architecture.

I have made CUDA7.5 project on Visual studio 2010, and just added

```
#include <afxwin.h>
```

to my default source file, kernel.cu.

Since afxwin.h needs Microsoft MFC libraries, I have changed my project properties to use Shared MFC libraries.

But when I tried to compile it, error occurs.
ERROR NO C2015, C2017, C2143, which is about grammar error occurs for "atlbase.h" which I never modified.

Do you have any solutions to use ATL on CUDA?

PS. ATL is working well on MVCC, not a problem of absence of header file, dlls and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CUDA C++ front end is known to fail on very complex template declarations (at least boost, eigen, QT have been reported here to fail to compile when included into a `.cu` file).

The only solution is to quarantine the ATL code into `.cpp` files and not include those headers into `.cu` files. nvcc will not attempt to send code within `.cpp` files through the CUDA C++ parser and there will be no errors. You might need to provide wrapper functions in your `.cu` file(s) to link the ATL containing code to the CUDA code, depending on your application design.

If you have a real usage case for using ATL inside a `.cu` file, I would suggest contacting NVIDIA developer support and raising a bug report/feature request.